# Как отредактировать альбом в aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Можно ли отредактировать альбом в `aiogram`?

Боту прислали альбом, и потом в альбоме изменили фото. Как сделать, чтобы бот заменял у себя фото в альбоме, когда его меняет пользователь?

Comment: `edited_message_handler`??

Comment: @oleksandrigo Да, это я знаю. Проблема в том что незнаю как изменить фото именно в альбоме. Например пользователь прислал 5 фото боту, и пользователь решил сменить второе фото. Как боту узнать что изменили именно второе фото?